# How to get 1-ethyl-3-isopropylbenzene fron benzene

Tags: reaction-mechanism

[image]

I have to synthesize the compound shown above in a multi-step synthesis. My biggest issue is that I have no idea how to obtain one of the alkyl group in the meta-position. Getting the first alkyl group is fairly easy, but I don't know where to go from there.

Comment: Using a meta-directing group is a great idea. For instance, I could introduce a nitro group in the meta position. But where do I proceed from here? How can I transform the nitro group into an alkyl group.

Comment: 1) FC Acylation to make acetophenone 2)Alkylation 3) Clemmensen or Wolff-Kishner reduction to remove the carbonyl

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the answers, everyone! Could you please elaborate on what you mean by 'Alkylation'? Specifically, what are you referring to?
 
@Harikrishnan M your method with FC after Nitration will sadly not work. The Nitro group deactivates the ring, causing FC reaction to no occur.

Comment: What specific conditions would those be? If I were to write this in an exam, which reagents and conditions should I include

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Step 1 - Friedel-Crafts acetylation of benzene with acetyl chloride/AlCl3 to give acetophenone as described [here](https://www.prepchem.com/synthesis-of-acetophenone/)

Step 2 - Alkylation of acetophenone with 2-chloropropane/AlCl3 as documented in section 11.3 [here](https://egyankosh.ac.in/bitstream/123456789/59581/1/Unit11.pdf). The exact isopropylation reaction is described [here](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ja01531a023)

Step 3 - reduction of the carbonyl by Clemmensen [details here](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/%7Eharding/IGOC/C/clemmensen_reduction.html)/Wolff-Kishner [details here](http://www.chem.ucla.edu/%7Eharding/IGOC/W/wolff_kishner_reduction.html) or sodium borohydride followed by acid catalysed hydrogenation

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response! I have one question: Does the ketone introduced in your initial step deactivate the ring, thereby preventing further Friedel-Crafts reactions

Comment: Any electron-withdrawing group deactivates the ring, but depending on the conditions the reaction can still be done - I have added another reference to my answer.